# How can I convert a string with square brackets into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, advanced-custom-fields

I got this from the name attribute of a field

```
name="field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name]"
```

after serializing the form, I got this:

```
array('field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name]'=>'value')
```

and I need to convert that into the following array:

```
$field = array (
         'a' => array (
                [2] => array (
                       'b' => array (
                              [0] => array (
                                     'c' => array (
                                            [1] => array (
                                                 'field_name'=>'value'
                                            )
                                      )
                               )
                        )
                  )
           )
    );
```

do I need some sort of foreach function or php can recognize this string as array?

Comment: Did you try this

Comment: I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440020/convert-string-with-square-brackets-to-php-array, but I cannot use json_decode  because my string does not have commas.

Comment: I also tried to use the id of the field, which looks like this: `id="field-a-2-b-0-c-1-field_name` by using `(explode('-',$id));` but the problem is that the result is not nested

Comment: $filed = Array "field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name] => value";      dd($filed);

Comment: thank you dejavuguy, let me try. What is the `did` command for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically update php array with unknown number of nestings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554468/dynamically-update-php-array-with-unknown-number-of-nestings)

Comment: Sorry for that I wanted dump(); die; function

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Not a duplicate. [The solution for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025532/7284356) is different but also simple.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the result nested, use `parse_str()`.

```
$text = "field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name]=value";
parse_str($text, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [field] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [b] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [c] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [field_name] => value
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

See https://3v4l.org/7nmFT

Comment: The `parse_str` function is intended for parsing a query string of an URL. I think that using it in this way may not be very reliable.

Comment: It seems to me the this is *exactly* the use case `parse_str` was intended for. The string originates from an html text-input attribute `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get values in brackets with the regular expression, and then reduce it to the array that you want:

```
$key = 'field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name]';
$value = 'value';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\[([^[]+)\]/', $key, $matches);

$keys = array_reverse($matches[1]);
$result = array_reduce($keys, function ($array, $item) {
    return array($item => $array);
}, $value);
```

**Explanation**

In the regular expression `\[([^[]+)\]`:

- `([^[]+)` is matches any symbol except opening bracket, one or more
  times, and gets it into the capturing group (I hope you will not have nested brackets);
- `\[...\]` is literally matches brackets around.

The `preg_match_all` function should populate the `$matches` array with following data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [a]
            [1] => [2]
            [2] => [b]
            [3] => [0]
            [4] => [c]
            [5] => [1]
            [6] => [field_name]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 2
            [2] => b
            [3] => 0
            [4] => c
            [5] => 1
            [6] => field_name
        )
)
```

The `$matches[0]` have values of a full match and the `$matches[1]` have values of our first and only capturing group. We have interested only in capturing group values.

Then with the `array_reduce` function we can simply go through keys in the reverse order, and sequentially wrap our value into an array.

Comment: Very nice.  I was struggling with the regex.. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode function to do it. But the values should have space in between them, for example "Hello World" in which the values would be in `Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world )` but in your case it would be like `Array ( [0] => field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name] )` until $name as space in-between the characters or word.

```
$name="field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name]"
$name_array = explode(" ",$name);
print_r ($name_array);
```

Comment: thank you Balaji, however that does not make the array nested, right?

Comment: yes, it is not. I think Rei, snippets will do the exact job you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:
https://codebrace.com/editor/b06588218

I have used regex match twice to match variable name and arrays

`/[(.+?)]/`
matches any values in the array where "?" is lazy matching.
while following regex
`/^[^[]+/` matches the variable name.

I have used [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to create variable from string extracted from above regex

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [b] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [c] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [field_name] => value
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When testing your problem on my PHP server with this test code

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="field[a][2][b][0][c][1][field_name]">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
<form>
<pre>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['field']))
    print_r($_POST['field']);
?>
</pre>
```

I got the following response (after entering the word "hello" into the text box and clicking the "OK" button):

```
Array ( [a] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [b] => 
        Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [1] => 
        Array ( [field_name] => hello ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Admittedly, it was formatted nicer, but I am posting from my smartphone, so, please, forgive me for not formatting it again manually.

So, to me it is not quite clear why OP needs extra code to solve his/her problem.